# Smarter CSV and Uploaded CSV File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

For my application I am uploading a file via `file_field_tag`. How do I use that file with SmarterCSV? I have tried something like this `SmarterCSV.process(@file.tempfile.path)` and it just returns an empty array even though there is data in the CSV.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of smarter_csv are you using? 
Try the latest version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what @file is, but if from a typical form and assigned something like:

```
@file = params[:resource][:file_tag_name]
```

then try:

```
SmarterCSV.process(@file.original_filename)
```

or with CSV:

```
CSV.parse(@file.original_filename)
```

The object that Rails creates in the params hash for a file upload is an instance of a subclass of the IO class, so you need to get to the underlying file to pass it to SmarterCSV.

For more information about how Rails handles file uploading, please see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#what-gets-uploaded

Comment: @file is an ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object. I tried the above SmartCSV example and I received the following error, 'Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory'

Comment: Are you sure the data in the uploaded file is valid CSV?  Perhaps try the alternative CSV.parse method.

Comment: smarter_csv is a replacement for CSV -- not the other way around

Answer (score 6):

The proposed answer does not work.

If you however do it like this:

```
    clients_data = params[:file_categories]
    clients = SmarterCSV.process(clients_data.tempfile, {:chunk_size => 1, :key_mapping => {:ca_id => :id, :ca_desc => :name}})
```

This works fine.  You need to use tempfile instead of original_filename.

Comment: Using the `tempfile` instance variable is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SmarterCSV.process(@file.original_filename) will not work since it is looking for a location where the file is stored.

You need to use

SmarterCSV.process(params[:file].tempfile, {:col_sep => "\t", :row_sep => "\n"})

with tab delimited data "\t" and rows are separated by new lines "\n"